# Unable to boot virtual machine after ubuntu dist-upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I recently upgraded my kernel with `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

When I try to boot my virtual machine with `vagrant up` on my existing VM, I get the following error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'myvirtualmachine' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> myvirtualmachine: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> myvirtualmachine: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> myvirtualmachine: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    myvirtualmachine: Adapter 1: nat
    myvirtualmachine: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> myvirtualmachine: Forwarding ports...
    myvirtualmachine: 8092 (guest) => 9000 (host) (adapter 1)
    myvirtualmachine: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> myvirtualmachine: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> myvirtualmachine: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.


Command: ["startvm", "8b5f97cb-b593-4610-989d-6445fbcb7d0e", "--type", "headless"]


Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'myvirtualmachine' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

I tried to reload the VM to no avail. Even rebuilding the VM from scratch didn't help.

What can I do to get my VM back ?

Versions: virtualbox 5.1.10 r112026, vagrant 1.8.7, ubuntu 16.10, linux 4.8.0-28-generic

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it. It seems that dist-upgrade doesn't rebuild virtual box kernel modules. You have to reinstall virtualbox entirely:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-5.1 virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

I also tried `sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox-dkms` (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/677051/438785)) but it didn't works for me. The complete reinstallation of virtualbox seems the way to go.

Comment: I was just going to post this, you answered your own question and beat me to it (ha ha), But yes, I had this exact same issue some time ago, I had to remove and reinstall Virtualbox and dkms.